# Azure Resource Manager connection: Failed to obtain the Json Web Token(JWT) using service principal client ID

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

I'm following tutorial to deploy ARM with Azure DevOps pipeline, but getting error. I wonder what is wrong? Error happens with "Azure Resource Manager connection". It find all subsc correctly, but cannot move forward.

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-tutorial-pipeline
```

> Failed to obtain the Json Web Token(JWT) using service principal client ID.
>
> Exception Message:
>
> AADSTS700016: Application with identifier '111117a0-1c4f-486f-8765-e19669693333' was not found in the directory '11111041-ba57-4f49-866b-06c297c12222'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant. Trace ID: 1174e46d-22fb-456e-9c18-450c95080b00
>
> Correlation ID: 333c3a0e-42f4-41d7-83c1-f8e3e3a83274 Timestamp: 2020-04-07 10:07:14Z

Answer (score -4):

I created Service Principal automatically and now it works!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)